# Most Popular Items in Document Library count zero - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013 Document Library there is a option in ribbon "**Most Popular Items**" when i click, its show me zero count.

Image is attached for more clarification.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i get count from database (WSS_UsageApplication), by running query from "proc_GetSlowestPages" procedure.

[Reference here](https://tahazubair.blogspot.qa/2016/09/sharepoint-statistics.html)

Answer (score 3):

Is there any data in the Web Analytics reports for your site collection? (Go here) http://Yoursite.com/sites/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSiteCollection

If all of those are empty there may be an issue with Web Analytics in your SharePoint farm. Then you might want to look at this troubleshooting guide:

http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/